# Get logged time from Jira for user per month

Tags: c#, .net, jira, jira-rest-api

I must collect statistic how much time user logged in Jira as sum using C# and JIRA Rest API.

So i think about next workflow :

> as Admin, get all projects `->`
>
> for each project get all issues `->`
>
> for each issue get all worklogs `->`
>
> from each worklog get logged time for needed user + apply date filters(user name can be as
>   input parameter).

For me, it isn't good solution cause it contains many loops, but i can't find any other.

Has anybody know other solution?

Answer (score -1):

Hope i understand you right)

It can be done by Jira tools. I recommend using the 'Time Sheet' report. Run a query that selects you desired issues and save this filter after the query has been run. Next, head to the project overview - https://.com/browse/ choose 'Reports' from the sidebar and click 'Time Sheet Report'.When selecting the report options, make sure to use your newly created filter, if the filter covers multiple projects you would want to make sure to select 'All Projects' from the 'Projects' field.

Comment: i want to write console app using C# and Jira Rest api... so your answer not exact what I want

Comment: sorry, i think you want do this task by any tools.Can you please edit your question then?